# Saving memory, huge array alternative c programming

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I'm using an two arrays (unsigned int) with dimensions: 20000x20000.

I have a lot of empty spacing inside the arrays, many zeros or nulls.

There is something I can do to save memory?, because I'm running out of it.

I tried reading from a list in a file, but it's extremely slow.

I have heard that in other languages they have vectors.

Comment: The term you want to Google for is "sparse arrays", I believe.

Comment: You might also want to look at `mmap`.

Comment: Don't have such a huge array in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), which basically works by storing entries as a list of `(index1, index2, value)`, and only has entries for nonzero elements.